# Copying files with long names

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Good morning, 
I have some problems with copying/moving files from an old server(Win 2008 Server R2) to a new server (windows 2012 R2).
I tried to simply copying with admin credentials but I get an error of filenames too long.
I tried also with Total Commander which returns an error insufficient privileges, even if I do it with an administrator account and launching it as admin.

NB:  update (2919355) from Windows Update, updates 2932046, 2937592, 2938439, 2934018, and 2959977 is installed.

Can you suggest further solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Rename a directory to shorthen the path or create a share in the file structure and copy from there

Comment: I solved this by using your advice. I also noted that a patch that solves this issue was released.
The patch that fixes this is the KB 2919355 for Windows 2012 Server R2.

In my server was installed  KB 2919355 of  18/03/2014, another version was released  on 05/05/2014 you can consult this site for more details https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42334  .

Comment: Glad to know it helped, will write as a answer then, will add your link in it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename a directory to shorthen the path or create a share in the file structure and copy from there.

From the link of gave by Francesco, the problem seem now patched for such issue. (https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42334)

KB2919355 for Windows 2012R2: Including **KB2891362**   *A file copy operation fails when files or folders have long paths in Windows Explorer*